# Leaderboard command for JSON database

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I have a leveling system, code below, that uses a JSON database that sorts the data like this `{"626916199783071750":{"xp":94,"level":12}` I want to make a command that shows a leader board of all of the members in order of their level.
Code

```
nst Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const fs = require("fs");
let db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./database.json", "utf8"));

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // ignore bots

    // if the user is not on db add the user and change his values to 0
    if (!db[message.author.id]) db[message.author.id] = {
        xp: 0,
        level: 0
      };
    db[message.author.id].xp++;
    let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
    if(userInfo.xp > 100) {
        userInfo.level++
        userInfo.xp = 0
        message.reply("Congratulations, you level up")
    }
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(cmd === "rank") {
        let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x4286f4)
        .addField("Level", userInfo.level)
        .addField("XP", userInfo.xp+"/100");
        if(!member) return message.channel.sendEmbed(embed)
        let memberInfo = db[member.id]
        let embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x4286f4)
        .addField("Level", memberInfo.level)
        .addField("XP", memberInfo.xp+"/100")
        message.channel.sendEmbed(embed2)
    }
    fs.writeFile("./database.json", JSON.stringify(db), (x) => {
        if (x) console.error(x)
      });
})

client.login(config.token)
```

BTW im using discord.js v12+

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort JSON data as you provided, here is solution

```js
// Your database
const members = [
  {"626916199783071750":{"xp":94,"level":7}},
  {"626916199783071750":{"xp":94,"level":22}},
  {"626916199783071750":{"xp":94,"level":12}}
];

// Sort function
members.sort(function(a, b) {
  const keyA = a[Object.keys(a)[0]].level,
        keyB = b[Object.keys(a)[0]].level;
  // Compare
  // (swap -1 and 1 to change sort order)
  if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
  if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
  return 0;
});
// Result
console.log(members);
```

Comment: My database has all of the different users next to each other not one under another does this matter? also im putting this in my database.json file?

Comment: If the structure of each entry is the same as you provided in your question, it doesn't matter how much users there is (well, it depends on server hardware), but this sort function will sort them.

Comment: this is javascript code. Im putting it in a json file?, im confused

Comment: Nope) You read and parse your JSON here: `let db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./database.json", "utf8"));`, then you work with `db` array and send data to user. I don't know in what format data is in this file. You provided `{"626916199783071750":{"xp":94,"level":12}}`, I wrote sort function for it... If data is in different structure, then you need to alter this function)

Comment: ok thank you. i have not defined members in my index.js file though so it is giving me an error. how should i define members?

Comment: im sorry for the dumb questions its just that I also tried is as `db` because that is what i defined the database file as but It keeps saying it is not a funtion.